# How to run any program on domain with certain times

Tags: java, php, selenium

I want to make a program that automate login a website then gets data from there with certain times without being called from me or anyone else like datatabese jobs.My problem is I don't know how to run this program from my domain with certain times.

I searched the web then I found selenium driver, some web scrapers and so. These are all working(can do what to do) that when I run the project from my computer via java or reach that files from my domain(PHP or whatever).

Briefly, how could I make a program that automate login(it's not important login stuff just must doing something without being touch its ok for me) .

Comment: Do you own the server where your program is? If so, what is your OS?

Comment: yes i do , Windows OS

Comment: You can use [scheduled tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) for this on Windows servers.